# Solving homogeneous linear systems using Sympy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, sympy

I'm teaching myself linear algebra, and I'm trying to learn the corresponding Numpy and Sympy code alongside it.

My book presented the following matrix:

```
example1 = Matrix([[3,5,-4,0],[-3,-2,4,0],[6,1,-8,0]])
```

with the instructions to determine if there is a nontrivial solution. The final solution would be `x = x3 * Matrix([[4\3],[0],[1]])`. (Using Jupyter's math mode, I used the following to represent the solution:)

```
$$\pmb{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{3}x_3\\0\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = 
x_3\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{3}\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \\
= x_3\pmb{v} \text{, where }\pmb{v} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{3}\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
```

How can I now solve this in Sympy? I've looked through the documentation, but I didn't see anything, and I'm at a bit of a loss. I know that errors tend to be thrown for free variables. Is there a way to determine nontrivial solutions and the corresponding general solution using Sympy, considering that nontrivial solutions are reliant upon free variables? Or is `np.linalg` generally more preferred for this type of problem?

Comment: I'm sure you could use either, but sympy would be the tool of choice for symbolic math and exact solutions. Linalg is the top if you want a fast numeric solution. Define your problem properly and use the tool that fits best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linear system so

```
>>> linsolve(Matrix([[3,5,-4,0],[-3,-2,4,0],[6,1,-8,0]]))
FiniteSet((4*tau0/3, 0, tau0))
```

The `tau0` is the free parameter that you refer to as `x3`.